# Python socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, sockets, server, port, host

i made a python listener(server) on my vps 
but when i give the server and client the ip addreess of vps and port 8585 
this error shows:
error  : 
`socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`
i use python version 2 in vps
i use python version 3 in my PC

my server code :

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ip = raw_input("ip : ")
ip = str(ip)
port = raw_input("port : ")
port = int(port)
s.bind((ip,port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    s.send("welcome !")
    print (addr, "connected.")`
```

client :

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = input("HOST : ")
HOST = str(HOST)
PORT = input("PORT : ")
PORT = int(PORT)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
buff = 1024
data = s.recv(buff)
print(data)`
```

Answer (score 1):

In the server you have:

> ```
> c, addr = s.accept()
> s.send("welcome !")
> ```

You must do the `send` on the connected socket to the client and not on the listener socket, i.e. it should be `c.send` instead of `s.send`.

Comment: thanks i fixed c.send(),but about the part that you said "You must do the send on the connected socket to the client and not on the listener socket" it already sends text from listener to client!! :| i don't see any problem with that!

Comment: @MohammadrezaBahari: The listener (s) is not connected to anything which means any attempts to use it for sending will fail because there is no destination known for the data. One can only send data on a connected socket (c), i.e. the one returned from `accept`.